# Extending Devise SessionsController to authenticate using JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I am trying to build a rails API for an iphone app. Devise works fine for logins through the web interface but I need to be able to create and destroy sessions using REST API and I want to use JSON instead of having to do a POST on the sessions controller and having to parse the HTML and deal with a redirect.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController  
  def create
    super
  end  
  def destroy
    super
  end  
end
```

and in config/routes.rb I added:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :sessions, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

rake routes shows the routes are setup properly:

```
   api_v1_sessions POST   /api/v1/sessions(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"api/v1/sessions"}
    api_v1_session DELETE /api/v1/sessions/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"api/v1/sessions"}
```

When I POST to /user/sessions everything works fine. I get some HTML and a 302.

Now if I POST to /api/v1/sessions I get:

> Unknown action
>   AbstractController::ActionNotFound

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json'   -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions   -d "{'user' : { 'login' : 'test', 'password' : 'foobar'}}"
```

Comment: This will also work and is much simpler:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22582952/2555008

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is what finally worked.

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController  
  def create  
    respond_to do |format|  
      format.html { super }  
      format.json {  
        warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")  
        render :status => 200, :json => { :error => "Success" }  
      }  
    end  
  end  
  def destroy  
    super  
  end  
end
```

Also change routes.rb, remember the order is important.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "api/v1/sessions" }
devise_scope :user do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :sessions, :only => [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
end

resources :users
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more?  Are you passing in login and password to authenticate?

Comment: One thing to add to this:  I originally had a custom login view under app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb.  I had to move this to a new view folder to match the custom controller name/namespace.

Answer (score 10):

I ended up using a combination of @akshay's answer and @mm2001's answer.

```
class Api::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    render :json => {:success => true}
  end

  def destroy
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
    render :json => {}
  end

  def failure
    render :json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login Failed"]}
  end
end
```

... and in the devise initializer, I had to do this to get the #create method to use my `:recall` handler

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html, :json]
```

This is with Devise 1.5.1 and Rails 3.1.

Comment: +1 for the info on `config.navigational_formats`. One thing that may make this more robust in case you happen to update devise; You can just override the Devise::SessionsController.auth_options to return your failure method and then use the default implementations for everything else instead of implementing create and destroy yourself (assuming the default response is sufficient). `def auth_options super.merge({:recall => "#{controller_path}#failure" }) end`

Comment: Oh, by the ways, I'm on devise 2.0.4 and rails 3.2. So that may affect whether others can do what I did.

Comment: This works great, but I suggest returning a 401 for failure condition. `render :json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login Failed"]}, status: 'unauthorized'`

Comment: @mahemoff: excellent advice! however, it seems that status needs to be a symbol. `render :json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login Failed"]}, status: :unauthorized`

Comment: http://blog.observationpoint.org/post/52084218731/using-json-with-devise-invitable-for-ajax-invitations

Answer (score 9):

A recent answer here: http://jessehowarth.com/devise has some more detail (per [Using Devise 1.3 to authenticate JSON login requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973327/using-devise-1-3-to-authenticate-json-login-requests))

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by creating a small service that dispenses authentication tokens. I wrote a blog post about it: http://matteomelani.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/authentication-for-mobile-devices/.
You can also get the code here: https://github.com/matteomelani/Auth-Token-Service-Prototype.

Comment: It seems like there is a security flaw with this technique in that it circumnavigates the Lockable module, maybe I'm wrong about this...

Answer (score 1):

From the rdoc for devise's #devise_scope:

Sets the devise scope to be used in the controller. If you have custom routes,
you are required to call this method (also aliased as :as) in order to specify
to which controller it is targetted.

```
as :user do
  get "sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

Notice you cannot have two scopes mapping to the same URL. And remember, if
you try to access a devise controller without specifying a scope, it will
raise ActionNotFound error.

It looks like you need to wrap it in a #as block:

```
as :user do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :sessions, :only => [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: According to this URL https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

The way he layed his code is correct. I am also facing the same bug as him.

Comment: No, it's not.  The rdoc pretty clearly states that if you subclass a devise controller, the route in which you call it needs to be wrapped in an #as or a #devise_scope block, or else you'll get an ActionNotFound error.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to creating/destroying sessions is to use Devise's `token_authenticatable` module, and then update the other functions in your API so that they take the token as a mandatory parameter. This is arguably a more ReSTful design, since it retains statelessness (i.e., there's no session state anywhere). Of course, this advice holds for your JSON API, but I wouldn't recommend the same for your HTML UI (long token strings in your browser's URL bar are not a pretty sight).

See [here](http://zyphdesignco.com/blog/simple-auth-token-example-with-devise) for an example.

Comment: This was removed from Devise in v3.1.0, FWIW.  http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure navigation-formats should be used, an API isn't really that...

Per this [blog post](http://blog.observationpoint.org/post/52084218731/using-json-with-devise-invitable-for-ajax-invitations) just add

```
respond_to :html, :json
```

to your controllers.