# How does "respond_with_navigational" work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with Devise and DeviseInvitable to manage authentication in my app and I'm having some trouble adding AJAX support to InvitationsController#update. The controller in DeviseInvitable looks like this:

```
# invitations_controller.rb

# PUT /resource/invitation                                                                                                 
def update
  self.resource = resource_class.accept_invitation!(params[resource_name])

  if resource.errors.empty?
    set_flash_message :notice, :updated
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_accept_path_for(resource)
  else
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :edit }
  end
end
```

This works well when `resource.errors.empty? == true` and we execute:

```
respond_with resource, :location => after_accept_path_for(resource)
```

(i.e. invitations/update.js.erb is rendered and my javascript calls are made). The problem is that when `resource.errors.empty? == false`, and we execute:

```
respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :edit }
```

the server says:

```
Rendered invitations/update.js.erb (1.4ms)
```

but my javascript calls are not being run. Can anyone explain what `respond_with_navigational` is supposed to be doing? I've been googling for hours and I haven't found an explanation of this api anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, I figure out what `respond_with_navigational` is doing. It's defined in the Devise base classes as such:

```
def respond_with_navigational(*args, &block)
    respond_with(*args) do |format|
      format.any(*navigational_formats, &block)
    end
end
```

and, `navigational_formats` is defined in Devise as well:

```
# Returns real navigational formats which are supported by Rails
def navigational_formats
    @navigational_formats ||= Devise.navigational_formats.select{ |format| Mime::EXTENSION_LOOKUP[format.to_s] }
end
```

So, it's basically a wrapper for `respond_with()`. In order to get this to work, I had to add the following to my InvitationsController:

```
respond_to :html, :js
```

and now, `update.js.erb` is being rendered properly.

Comment: Came here because of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9154096/18706 (in case anyone's looking for a practical example of using it).

Comment: Also, this is a description in the default initializer: https://gist.github.com/3824340

Comment: 2018 right now, and I am having an issue with the EXACT same problem in the same context. Thank you.