# Custom devise sessions controller is not redirecting on error (:recall => not happening)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller

I am overriding **Device sessions controller**... It works (I can log in with json), but I cannot get it to redirect to another action on error:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#no")
    return invalid_login_attempt unless resource
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    #respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :status => 200, :json => { :success => true, :auth_token => resource.authentication_token, :user => resource } }
    end
  end

  def no
    puts "NO!"
    return render:json => {:success => false, :errors => alert}
  end


end
```

I also tried:

```
 if resource.nil?
   puts "NIL!"
 end
```

I always get the same default Devise json error in response to wrong sign_in credentials:

```
{error: "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Any solution found for this one?

Comment: Did you define a route for the #no action?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that if warden doesn't get a user from it's authenticate! action it throws a symbol to the failure app. Anything after that line is therefore irrelevant in the case of failure.

Change `authenticate!` to `authenticate` and it will return the user object for you to handle as you see fit.

Check the proxy.rb file in the warden gem for further details. 
[Documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/warden/1.2.1/Warden/Proxy#authenticate-instance_method)

Answer (score 1):

According to this similar thread ([Extending Devise SessionsController to authenticate using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857855/extending-devise-sessionscontroller-to-authenticate-using-json)), all you need to do is to include the following code:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html, :json]
```