# how to change the password in devise from iPhone app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am developing an web app that will be used by iphone app. I use devise as authentication and i can create a new user, login as the user and when login is done it gives out

```
{"user":{"authentication_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","email":"sample@example.com"}}
```

but how can i change the password using json.

Comment: Can you be more clear. What you are trying to do. Are you building an api that will be used by Iphone and in that app you want to add a feature of changing password or is it something else ?

Comment: yes, you are right I am trying to add the change password feature

Comment: Make sure that you have enabled token_authenticatable in the user model and Read through [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password]) article

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will need to build an API for this, utilizing Devises JSON (Warden) to respond to JSON etc

reference to help point you in the right direction [creating sessions with devise](http://jessehowarth.com/devise)

Searching SO also yields
[Ajax login with devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857855/extending-devise-sessionscontroller-to-authenticate-using-json)